# Computing an expectation in an $M/M/c$ loss system with two channels

Tags: probability, probability-theory, queueing-theory

> Consider an $M/M/c$ loss system (called station 1) with arrival rate
>   $\lambda$, where customers who find all channels busy (and are lost)
>   are served at a secondary infinite channel facility (called station
>   2). Customers who are served at station $1$ leave the system and do
>   not go to station 2. Service times at both stations follow some
>   arbitrary distribution with service rate $\mu$.
>
> Let $N_i$ be the number of customers at station $i$ in steady state $i
>  = 1, 2$. Compute $E(N_{2})$

I need help with this queue theory problem. I tried many things like finding first the joint distribution $P(N_1 = m, N_2 = n) = p_{mn}$ where $m = 0, 1, \ldots, c$ and n = 0, 1, ...  with not much luck.

I also tried to do this and find balance equations for $p_{mn}$ but again could not find much luck.

Maybe someone can please assist me. My book does not have many examples and I want to  understand this problem. Thanks